# Manually sort a linked list in the C programming language

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

How do you sort a linked list by name in a function in C?

```
struct rec{
    char name[20];
    int nr;
    struct rec *nextRec;
};
typedef struct rec Rec; /* synonym for struct rec */
typedef Rec *RecPtr; /* synonym for pointer */

void SortLinkedList(RecPtr *sPtr, int p_size);/* prototype */
int main() {
    RecPtr startPtr = NULL;
    /* filling upp the linked list... size = nr of nodes in list */
    SortLinkedList(&startPtr, size);
}

void SortLinkedList(RecPtr *sPtr, int p_size){
    int i, j;
    RecPtr tempPtr;
    RecPtr currentPtr;
    RecPtr nextPtr;
    currentPtr = *sPtr;
    nextPtr = currentPtr->nextRec;
    for( j = 0; j <= p_size; j++) { /* loop for nr of nodes */
        for(i = 0; i <= p_size -1 ; i++) { /* loop for one less than nr of nodes */
            if(strcmp(currentPtr->name, nextPtr->name) < 0) { /* it less than ...*/
                tempPtr = currentPtr;/* ...swap with temp */
                currentPtr = nextPtr; /* but this sorting doesn'nt work */
                nextPtr = tempPtr;
            }
           currentPtr = nextPtr;
           currentPtr = currentPtr->nextRec;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are just manipulating the pointers and not the objects themselves. When you sort a linked list, you necessary have to break links and re-make them.

For example, in your case there are three links and they have to be modified as specified in the brackets.

prevPtr->nextRec (This needs to be changed to point to nextPtr instead of currentPtr)
currentPtr->nextRec (This needs to be changed to point to nextPtr->nextRec instead of nextPtr)
nextPtr->nextRec (This needs to be changed to point to currentPtr)

You necessarily need to have a prevPtr and keep track of it in your program.

```
        nextRec                   nextRec           nextRec
```

prevPtr -------------->currentPtr ------------------------->nextPtr---------------------------> (nextPtr->nextRec)

Needs to be changed to

```
           nextRec           nextRec              nextRec
```

prevPtr ----------------------->nextPtr ------------------> currentPtr-------------------> (nextPtr->nextRec)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your are only manipulating the RecPtr variables, which has no permanent effect, when you should manipulate the `nextRec` fields of the structs in the list instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not to answer your question, but a couple of observations:

- using typedefs that hide the fact that something is a pointer is generally considered bad style
- if you need sorting, then a linked list is not the best structure to use - you may be better of with an array

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**: *The following is most likely overkill for what you're wanting to do.  But I'm frustrated trying to track down a subtle but nasty bug and need a distraction.*

If I may offer some suggestions...

First of all, IMO it's easier to insert items into a list in order than to sort an unordered list; what I would do is create an insertInOrder function that takes your list head, the new element to be added, and a predicate (a pointer to a function) that compares records, and returns the new head of the list:

```
Rec *insertInOrder(Rec *head, Rec *new, int (*cmp)(Rec *, Rec *))
{
  if (head == NULL)
  {
    return new;
  }
  else if (cmp(new, head) < 0) // new is "less than" head
  {
    new->nextRec = head;
    return new;                // new becomes the new head of the list
  }
  else
  {
    Rec *tmp = head;
    /**
     * Find the first element in the list that is not "less than" new
     */
    while (tmp->nextRec != NULL && cmp(new, tmp->nextRec) > 0)
    {
      tmp = tmp->nextRec;
    }
    if (tmp->nextRec == NULL)
    {
      // insert new at end of list
      tmp->nextRec = new;
      new->nextRec = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      // insert new before tmp->nextRec
      new->nextRec = tmp->nextRec;
      tmp->nextRec = new;
    }
    // keep the current list head
    return head;
  }
}
```

Now you can order the list based on different criteria.  The `cmp` argument points to a function that takes two record pointers and compares them, returning -1 if the first argument is "less than" the second, 1 if the first argument is "greater than" the second, and 0 if they compare equal.  For example, if you want to sort by names, define a function like

```
int compareNames(Rec *e1, Rec *e2)
{
  int r = strcmp(e1->name, e2->name);
  if (r < 0) return -1;
  if (r > 0) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

and call insertInOrder as

```
head = insertInOrder(head, new, compareNames);
```

To sort the list, given a particular predicate: starting at the head, remove one element at a time from the existing list and add it to a new list, using the indicated predicate:

```
Rec *sortLinkedList(Rec *head, int (*cmp)(Rec *, Rec *))
{
  Rec *newList = NULL;

  while (head)
  {
    Rec *tmp = head;
    head = head->nextRec;
    tmp->nextRec = NULL;
    newList = insertInOrder(newList, tmp, cmp);
  }
  return newList;
}
...
head = sortLinkedList(head, compareNr);
...
head = sortLinkdeList(head, compareNames);
...
head = sortLinkedList(head, compareSomethingElse);
```

Like Neil, I'm not terribly fond of typedefs for pointer types; experience has shown me that they cause more problems than they're worth.

Comment: +1; insertion sort is an online algorithm and therefore well suited for linked lists, although it's not really efficient for sorting a large, pre-existing unsorted list...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to changed the order of a linked list then at some stage you are going to have to write to the `nextRec` pointers on the link list. As the only assignments that you make are to local pointer variables you are not making any changes to the list.

You don't do any resetting between the `i` loop and the `j` loop so it's hard to see how your algorithm guarantees not to go beyond the end of the list, although often it's not going to move very far.

If the `strcmp` test doesn't trigger for two iterations then it will always leave `nextPtr` alone and always assign `currentPtr` to `nextPtr->nextRec` so neither `nextPtr` nor `currentPtr` will change.

```
currentPtr = nextPtr;
currentPtr = currentPtr->nextRec;
```

Do you really mean to use `i++` in the loop body as well as the increment part of the for loop?

What is your sorting algorithm? Note that if you need to swap two elements position in a singly linked list then you will need to retain the previous nodes to the elements being swapped so that you can adjust the previous nodes' "next" pointer.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort a linked list with bubble sort easily(iterating through it, keeping track of the i-1th element in case of swapping). You could also do a quicksort rather easily(in fact, I've heard some people suggest that quicksort makes more sense on a linked list than on an array).

Comment: Ok that was my intention, do you have an example of bubble sort on a linked list?

Comment: linked lists don't allow (efficient) random access, which means you're restricted in the choice of pivot, resulting in poor quicksort performance; a stack-based mergesort is the algorithm of choice when sorting linked lists

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list either through selection sort or bubble sort. Instead of data you need to swap the pointer. Below I am giving both sort examples which may helpful to your issue.

```
struct link
{
    int data;
    struct link *next;
};
selection(struct link **first)
{
    struct link *p,*q,*pp,*qq,*temp;
    pp=p=*first;
    while(p->next!=NULL)
    {
    q=p->next;
        while(q!=NULL)
        {
            if(p->data > q->data)
            {
                if(p==*first)
                {
                    if(q==p->next)
                    {
                        p->next=q->next;
                        q->next=p;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp=q->next;
                        q->next=p->next;
                        p->next=temp;
                        qq->next=p;
                    }
                    *first=q;
                    pp=*first;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(q==p->next)
                    {
                        p->next=q->next;
                        q->next=p;
                        pp->next=q;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp=q->next;
                        q->next=p->next;
                        p->next=temp;
                        qq->next=p;
                        pp->next=q;
                    }
                 }
                temp=p;
                p=q;
                q=temp;
            }
            qq=q;
            q=q->next;
        }
        pp=p;
        p=p->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

bable(struct link **first)
{
    struct link *p,*q,*lt,*pp,*temp;
    lt=NULL;
    p=*first;
    while((*first)->next!=lt)
    {
        pp=p=*first;
        while(p->next!=lt)
        {
            q=p->next;
            if((p->data)>(q->data))
            {
                if(p==*first)
                {
                    p->next=q->next;
                    q->next=p;
                    *first=q;
                    pp=*first;
                }
                else
                {
                    p->next=q->next;
                    q->next=p;
                    pp->next=q;
                }
                temp=p;
                p=q;
                q=temp;

            }
            pp=p;
            p=p->next;
        }
        lt=p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: needs to be edited for the code block. I would but not enough rep

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest merge-sort on the list as it is O(N Log N) while bubble-sort or insertion-sort are both O(N^2).

[Here's good example of a simple singly linked list merge sort](http://www.c.happycodings.com/Sorting_Searching/code10.html).

Comment: the example is not that good as traversing the list for partitioning (the loop in `mergesort()`) can be avoided by using a stack

Comment: True, you can partition on the fly using a stack so that you only do one partitioning pass as you go.  But even with traversal based partitioning, this should still be a faster sort than bubble sort or insertion sort by magnitude of the order.

Comment: You can also do a bidirectional merge sort where you sort groups of four instead of two... your merge 2 pairs of 2 lists down to just 2 lists forwards and save them with LIFO style rather than FIFO style, then you merge the subsequent two lists backwards.  This can be faster on larger lists which blow thru the cache because the second merge will usually grab the tail end of the most recent list out of the cache (L1 then L2).

Comment: I did some benchmarking: the algorithm you linked to needed nearly 15 seconds(!) to sort a list with 50000 random elements, performing only slightly better than insertion sort; in comparison, my stack-based mergesort implementation needed only 31 milliseconds; I'll post it once I get to do some code cleanup