# Referring to "C - Help understanding how to write a function within a function (list_map)"

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the same professor: I have read the forum:

[How to write a function within a function (list_map)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119558/c-help-understanding-how-to-write-a-function-within-a-function-listmap/2119913#2119913)

It is very helpful understanding the concept of the function but I'm not sure if I am using it right...

Here is my code.. Let me know if I am on the right track...

Assume that I have an array of 10 linked lists in which the linked lists holds ints

Now I would like to sort the list calling the list_map(); function

So my main looks something like this:

```
int x = 10;  
LLIST *mylist[x];  
bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);  
.  
.    
for(i=0; i< 10; i++)  
{    
 //Segfalt   
 list_map(mylist[i],sort);   
}
```

my list_map looks like:

```
void list_map( LLIST *list, void (*f)(void *) )  
{  
  printf("Sort");  
  f(list);  
}
```

and Sort:

```
void sort(LLIST *n) {  
//Sort Code  
}
```

The error I get is Segmentation fault when I run it.

Please excuse the lack of code, I know my sort function works, I have tested it already and it prints out each list. If you need to see something in more detail let me know I will provide it.

Comment: Can you use a debugger or printfs to narrow down the instruction that is segfaulting? This will lead quickly to an understanding of the problem

Comment: I tried doing a printf within the for loop before the call and it doesnt print.. If a print f is before the loop it will print.

Comment: It also doesnt do the printf in the list_map function

Comment: Can you edit your question and mark the segfaulting instruction in your code? I'm pretty sure this is a memory allocation error but the debugging exercise is good for you :-)

Comment: Note that 'printf()' (normally) buffers its output; you need to use 'fflush(stdout)' or 'fprintf(stderr, ...)' to ensure that your diagnostic printing completes properly.  We also need to see what is represented by the two 'dot' lines, sadly.

Comment: Whats happening in the .. area is reading a matrix of numbers from a text file and inserting them into the mylist[x]... That all works I have called the sort function with out using list_map() function and it sorts and prints.. the problem comes when using the list_map()... It gets too involved if I add more code, If you really need to see it then I will post more

Comment: Pretty much if I remove the list_map() function it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bzero zeroes out memory it does not allocate memory, use malloc

```
int x = 10;  
LLIST **mylist;  
mylist = (LLIST**)malloc(sizeof(LLIST *)*x);  
.  
.    
for(i=0; i< 10; i++)  
{    
 //Segfalt   
 list_map(mylist[i],sort);   
}

void list_map( LLIST *list, void (*f)(void *) )  
{  
  printf("Sort");  
  f(list);  
}
```

Comment: bzero is surely causing a segfault because its zeroing an undefined location in memory

Comment: is it implemented like bzero? I'm not familiar with much C code

Comment: ugh LLIST **mylist = (LLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LLIST *)*x).. sorry its late

Comment: I still get the Seg fault.. How do you use the debugger?

Comment: Pretty much if I remove the list_map() function it works... Well It doesn't have the Seg Error

Comment: Your sure you got output after that call to bzero?? If so then I am quite suprised!

Comment: I changed it to what you said (taking out the bzero)... I took out the list_map() to see if I get any seg errors and I didnt ... but when I ran it with the list_map().. I get the same errors..

Comment: it is also possible you were not supposed to have an array of pointers which is what LLIST *mylist[x]; implies.. you would want LLIST mylist[] isntead of LLIST *mylist[]

Comment: I tried just about anything even changing * in front of the functions

Comment: I was hopping it was something simple as LLIST **mylist = (LLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LLIST *)*x).

Comment: myprogram.c:16: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
myprogram.c:42: warning: passing argument 2 of \u2018list_map\u2019 from incompatible pointer type

Comment: thats some other stuff i get dont know if that will help you

Comment: LLIST **mylist = (LLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LLIST *)*lines); is line 16

Comment: should have been two *'s im new to stack overflow, it chomped it.. see my answer edit.. also this has turned into a discussion which I believe is discouraged feel free to email me

Comment: I tried what you posted.. I get the error  error: array size missing in \u2018mylist\u2019

Comment: why is it discouraged...? I know I am frusterated

Comment: thats becuase im dumb.. fixed

Comment: warning: passing argument 2 of \u2018list_map\u2019 from incompatible pointer type ... Thats at the function call

Comment: that warning is because your function pointer expects to have a void * argument and you gave it LLIST **

Comment: You have been a great help.. I will email you my code.. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you allocating mylist? Based on what you have here it looks like anything which accessed mylist would cause a segfault. Are you sure that should be `LLIST *mylist[x];` and not `LLIST mylist[x];`?

Comment: I forgot to add in bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);